# Allowing users to change 'from' address

Tags: security, email

I have a question about allowing users on a website to change the 'from' email address from something other than their registered address when they send an email from our website. We are allowing users to email files from their document storage on the site, but I have a concern that allowing them to change who it's from could be a security/spam problem. It just doesn't sit well with me, but I can't seem to articulate it well to my boss. Does anybody have any thoughts on this?